# Why does segmenting result in imprecise lengths?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

When I segment audio using this command

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -f segment -segment_time 60 output_%03d.wav
```

I would except to get segments exactly 60 second long.
What is produced is segments of 00:01:00.03 and 00:00:59.90

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'output_001.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.25.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.03, bitrate: 256 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
```

fourth segment

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'output_003.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.25.100
  Duration: 00:00:59.90, bitrate: 256 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: One word: Frames.

Answer (score 3):

Audio samples are chunked into frames during processing. If the frame size does not evenly divide the sampling rate, then frame boundaries won't be aligned at whole seconds. You can use the `asetnsamples` filter to reframe.

In your case, the sampling rate is 16000 Hz, so let's reframe to 160 samples per frame.

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -filter:a "asetnsamples=160" -f segment -segment_time 60 output_%03d.wav
```

Comment: Thank you that worked well.
Is an audio frame an arbitrary number of samples, what are the ramifications of reframing on other operations?

For others reading this `asetnsample` [is documented here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetnsamples)

Comment: Many audio codecs require a specific nb. of samples in a frame (however, ffmpeg will reframe automatically when needed). Uncompressed PCM streams don't.